# Fallo en autocompletado

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy tratando de llenar unos inputs dependiendo de el valor que tenga un input principal... me explico, tengo un formulario dentro de un div con un id para poder llamarlo desde un js

```
<div id="revisarCliente">

    <form role="form" method="POST" class="formularioVenta">

        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="box">

                <!--=====================================
                ENTRADA DEL CLIENTE
                ======================================--> 

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="" placeholder="Nombre de cliente" />

                        <input type="hidden" name="clienteNombre" id="clienteNombre">

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCliente" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar cliente</button></span>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--==============================================
                =            Direccion del cliente            =
                ===============================================-->

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span> 

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="" placeholder="Direccion de cliente">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--====  End of Direccion del cliente  ====-->

                <!--==============================================
                =            Telefono del cliente            =
                ===============================================-->

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span> 

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="" placeholder="Telefono de cliente">

                    </div>

                </div>
                <br>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar Orden</button>

        </div>

    </form>

    <div id="estado">Esperando input.</div>

</div>
```

en mi js tengo un codigo para hacer la busqueda por ajax y el llenado de los otros inputs

```
$(function(){
   /* Ponemos evento blur a la escucha sobre id nombre en id cliente. */
   $('#revisarCliente').on('blur','#cliente',function(){
      /* Obtenemos el valor del campo */
      var valor = this.value;
      /* Si la longitud del valor es mayor a 2 caracteres.. */
      if(valor.length>=3){

         /* Cambiamos el estado.. */
         $('#estado').html('Cargando datos de servidor...');

         /* Hacemos la consulta ajax */
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'cliente.php',
            data:{cliente:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         /* En caso de que se haya retornado bien.. */
         consulta.done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.telefono!==undefined){$('#revisarCliente #telefono').val(data.telefono);}
               if(data.direccion!==undefined){$('#revisarCliente #direccion').val(data.direccion);}
               $('#estado').html('Datos cargados..');
               return true;
            }
         });

         /* Si la consulta ha fallado.. */
         consulta.fail(function(){
            $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
            return false;
         });

      } else {
         /* Mostrar error */
         $('#estado').html('El nombre tener una longitud mayor a 2 caracteres...');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

y tengo otro en php donde hago la conexion y la busqueda

```
<?php

/* Conectar a una base de datos de MySQL invocando al controlador */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistemapos';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(!empty($_POST['cliente'])) { 
    $nombre = $_POST['cliente'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = :nombre";  
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll();

    //Verifica si no hay datos en la consulta
    if($arrDatos){
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
          if ($nombre = $row['nombre']) {
            $return = array ('direccion' => $row['direccion'],
                            'telefono' => $row['telefono'],
                            'nombre' => $row['nombre']);
          }      
        }

    } else {
            //Esto ocurre si el nombre está vacío solamente
            $arrDatos = array('error'=>'El nombre está vacío');
    }

//Imprimir los resultados 
echo json_encode($return);
}
```

antes me funcionaba, pero ahora no y solo entra a el error de ha habido un error contactando al servidor

> Editado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En network me aparecio eso y en respuesta me aparecieron los datos que yo estoy solicitando pero no me los imprime en los inputs

Comment: Tu consulta no debería ser con `like`, en lugar de `=`, `WHERE LIKE '%Gabri%'`

Comment: @HammerffallBK no, por que quiero que los datos sean exactos

Comment: entonces debería funcionar si capturas un nombre exacto que tienes en la db, y no lo esta haciendo?

Comment: @HammerffallBK no, no esta funcionando, no tengo idea del por que, estaba haciendo unas pruebas y si funcionaba correctamente, después cambie varios campos en la bd y dejo de funcionar, cabe aclarar que los campos de nombre, teléfono y dirección jamás se cambiaron

Comment: la llamada ajax, que error te esta devolviendo? remueve `dataType:'JSON'` de tu llamado ajax, y en la función `done`debe imprimir en tu consola lo que devuelve el llamado? igual y no esta encontrando datos de la db

Comment: Prueba el script PHP sin ajax, para que puedas ver si hay algún mensaje de error.

Comment: @HammerffallBK hice lo que me dijiste de quitar el datatype y ver que me marcaba en la consola, pero no me muestra nada en consola

Comment: @Triby ya probe el script de php entrando a la pagina e introduciendo un nombre directo en el query, y si me trae toda la informacion

Comment: en la parte de desarrollador del navegador, hay una opción que dice network, donde ves todos los js, css y html que cargas para la página, haz el llamado, y te aparecera el request que se hace con ajax, si te marca error, es que esta mal la ruta, si hace el llamado y te devuelve la misma respuesta, hay algo mal con el js

Comment: @HammerffallBK ya edite la pregunta junto con los screens que me aparecen en network y la respuesta

Comment: estas dando un `var_dump($arrDaros);`, esa es la sálida de un var_dump

Comment: @HammerffallBK si, no me habia fijado en eso, pero ya lo quite y en respuesta no me trae nada pero me sigue apareciendo el codigo en 200 (eso es success no?)

Comment: si, dale la impresión de `echo json_encode($arrDatos);`, y acuerdate de dejar tu js del lado de la vista de la forma correcta

Comment: @HammerffallBK dejo el `echo json_encode($arrDatos);` y no me muestra nada, pero si hago un `var_dump` a el array de `$return`, si me esta trayendo los datos de manera correcta

Comment: ya, es que tienes asignado `$arrDatos` en el `else`, y para que te devuelva el error cuando no encuentre algo debes hacerlo sobre la misma variable, ya sea `$arrDatos` o `$result`

Comment: no entendi muy bien tu explicacion ya que me dijiste que el error de el else esta en que lo asigno en $arrDatos y luego creo que te contradices... una pregunta es para que sirve si coloco die(json_encode($return));

Answer (score 1):

Mira, tu código podrias dejarlo de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

/* Conectar a una base de datos de MySQL invocando al controlador */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistemapos';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(!empty($_POST['cliente'])) { 
    $nombre = $_POST['cliente'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = :nombre";  
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll();

    //Verifica si no hay datos en la consulta
    if($arrDatos){
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
          if ($nombre = $row['nombre']) {
            // aqui asignas los datos que obtienes de la base de datos
            $return = array ('direccion' => $row['direccion'],
                            'telefono' => $row['telefono'],
                            'nombre' => $row['nombre']);
          }      
        }

    } else {
            //Esto ocurre si el nombre está vacío solamente, o no se encuentran datos en tu base de datos
            $return = array('error'=>'El nombre está vacío');
    }

//Imprimir los resultados 
echo json_encode($return);
}
```

el `$return` contiene el objeto para que tu llamada ajax, reciba datos si en la base de datos, encuentra o no el nombre que estas buscando, ahora si le agregas
`die(json_encode($return));`, hace la impresión del texto devuelto por la función y detiene la ejecución del script, y tu lógica esta erronea, si encuentra más de una vez el nombre Javier, Pedro o cualquier otro, en el `foreach`sobreescribes la variable con cada uno de los resultados, por lo cual solo te devolvera siempre el último nombre que este en la base de datos,

Comment: lo que esta causando conflicto es la palabra direccion no tengo ni idea del por que

Comment: las letras como por ejemplo la ñ y las letras con tilde, ¿Causan conflicto en JSON? por que estoy tratando de imprimir palabras que tienen acentos y ñ's y es donde se vuelve error

Comment: Puedes utilizar `echo json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` o `htmlentities` sobre los valores de direccion, telefono o nombre

Comment: Asegúrate de que todos tus datos están en UTF8, que es el juego de caracteres aceptado por json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

Por mi parte realizo este tipo de consultas de la siguiente forma:

Ajax

```
function creo() {

var id= $("#elid").val();
console.log(id);
$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'inc/consulta.php',
    data:{id},
    success:function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[0].nombre);
        $("#datito").attr("value",data[0].nombre);
    }
   });
  }
```

PHP

```
   <?php
   include('../conn/conexion.php');

   $json   =array();
   $id     =isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
   $sql    ="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = $id ";
   $result =mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta 
   a la base de datos");

  while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $json[]=$a;
    # code...
   }
   echo json_encode($json);

    // cerrar conexión de base de datos
  mysqli_close( $con );
  ?>
```

Ademas opino que deberias ver en la parte del network la sección de headers el ultimo resultado debe decir algo como form-data que es donde puedes ver que dato estas enviando a la consulta, ya que dices que no se realiza y entra al error de que no se ah contactado con el servidor.

Saludos

Comment: como retornas datos con acentos o caracteres especiales? lo intente con JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE pero no me da

Comment: Aplicandole esta linea al archivo de conexion  mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8");  y luego en el envio utilizando return json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);